# Turn a NDsolve output into an exponential one

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm new to Mathematica and I'm trying to convert the output of a NDSolve problem into an exponential one.
In particular I obtain the W(x) function ,but in the end I want to plot exp[W(x)]=Y(x).
I naively tried the following with no results though

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];

Mx = 100;
gx = 2;
gs = 106.75;
g = 100;
Mp = 10^19;
Y0 = 10^-20;
W0 = Log[Y0];
\[Sigma]v = 10^-6;

Clear[neq, f];
neq[x_Real, m_] := 
  NIntegrate[(gx/(2 Pi Pi)) Exp[-x Sqrt[1 + p p/(m m)]] p p, {p, 0, 
    Infinity}, MaxRecursion -> 50];
stot[x_] := (2 Pi Pi/45) gs Mx^3 /(x^3);
Yeq[x_, m_] := neq[x, m]/stot[x];
Weq[x_, m_] := Log[Yeq[x, m]];
RHS[x_, m_, \[Sigma]v_] := (0.264 Mp Mx gs \[Sigma]v/(Sqrt[g])) (Exp[
       2 Weq[x, m] - W[x]] - Exp[W[x]])/(x^2);
xmin = 10^-2; xmax = 10^2;
xdom = {x, xmin, xmax};
ODE = {W'[x] == RHS[x, Mx, \[Sigma]v]};
BC = {W[xmin] == W0};
Wsol = NDSolve[{W'[x] == RHS[x, Mx, \[Sigma]v], BC}, W, xdom, 
  Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]

LogLogPlot[Evaluate[Y[x] /. Log[Wsol]], {x, 10^-2, 10^2}, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Could you provide some background? Your equation seems a bit weird. Also you have constants that span 30 orders of magnitude, you should try to reparameterize the equations in order to have smaller constants.

Comment: Hi, I just added another question because your comment made me notice I wasn't looking at the right solution. 
So thanks! And also, if you want to take a look to the "general" problem of mine I'd be great ahah. 
Thanks in any case!

Comment: There must be something wrong with the magnitude of the parameter. You get `Derivative[1][W][1/100] == 5.27765*10^34` as intial condition, which is utopically high.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving your specific problem aside for a moment, I just wanted to show you that you can obtain a function of your solution directly using `NDSolveValue`, with syntax practically identical to `NDSolve`.

For instance, the example below solves a simple differential equation modeling exponential decay, and then reports the logarithm of that solution as output.

```
sol = 
  NDSolveValue[
    {a'[t] == -1/2 a[t], a[0] == 1},
    Log[a[#]] &,
    {t, 0, 20}
  ]
```

[image: Solution (Log of interpolating function) expressed as a pure function]

You can use that solution as a pure function in further processing, e.g. for plotting:

```
Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: plot of the solution from above, showing a linear decay with time]